# Create authentication in another AngularJS module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I have doubts on how to create a login page for the template [BlurAdmin](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin).

The Template has the index.html as masterpage. It has header, footer, sidebar, ... and the pages are loaded as template (ui-view).

But I would like to use login page the independent of index.html, I think the best way to create it using another ngApp, different from index.html, but how should I do? I looked much about, but the login.html is always loaded as a template (ui-view).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide your application into few steps, it could be useful. So you can create separate index.html file which will include all html from logins template. Of course, you can also add another angular to this separate page to handle logic, but keep in mind how much logic you will need to add to this page, maybe it will be easier to use something with less weight for the login page.

Anyway, as a result, you should have the second separate application with included scripts and styles as it already implemented in the main application. So the answer to your question - you should handle building process for the second application which will be you login SPA, and you will have two single page applications with different scripts in each, they can use different angular versions or even different Frameworks.

Comment: woow! It's a lot of weight for a simple login page! You have reason @Mikki , maybe I should choose another way. But I do not know what to do to not have to change the whole structure of BlurAdmin (masterpage in index.html).

Comment: @MateusVitali, In general, just try to cut out everything you need for the login page, so create index.html, after that include styles which are affect login page, and then add your `<script>`, wich will include logic for it. I assume you need to rewrite logic on your own if you wish to separate login.